# a good user agent for python webcrawler

Tags: python, web-crawler, user-agent

i'm making a python crawler and i'm thinking of a user agent.

can anyone think of a user agent.

or/and does anyone have a scheme

i thing of somthing like "urllib (compatible; owi bot; +owi.tk/bot)'(this is googlebot rewritten).

so can somone help me

Comment: I suppose, 99.9% sites and their owners don't care about UA string.

Comment: @kirilloid: And the ones that do care may just reject your request if you are a UA they don't know

Comment: @alan then just use any popular UA.

Comment: so should i use the crome of ff ua.

Comment: @kirilloid yes, that was my point (which I didn't make very well :)

Comment: I would use the IE 8 UA. It "works for me" on a few finicky [read: awfully setup] sites.

Comment: but i want to make my own? any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't just clone one. This would be SO wrong! There are good reasons for having a unique User-agent header value.

Answer (score 3):

Just make one up. Bonus points for making it possible to contact you if your bot does something wrong/bad/stupid/great. Specification is in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) sec. 14.43 (HTTP/1.1).

And PLEASE don't just copy something!

Also, [some practical stuff learned](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/06/07/testing-3-million-hyperlinks-lessons-learned) while crawling Stackoverflow & friends for bad links:

> From day 0 set yourself up with a proper User Agent String.